# How to get the Twig object out of the container?

Tags: php, slim-3, php-di

I'm using Slim Framework 3 with PHP-DI/Slim-Bridge. This is my container:

```
$builder->addDefinitions([
            'settings.displayErrorDetails' => true,

            'router' => get(Router::class),

            Twig::class => function(ContainerInterface $c) {
                $twig = new Twig(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', [
                   'cache'=> false
                ]);

                $twig->addExtension(new TwigExtension(
                    $c->get('router'),
                    $c->get('request')->getUri()
                ));

                return $twig;
            }
   ]);
```

How can I get the twig object back out of the container?
I tried $container->twig, but I'm not able to get the object back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$container->get(Twig::class)`.

I invite you to read [Getting started with PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/doc/getting-started.html#3-create-the-objects).